# Построение архитектуры БД для системы тестирования

Tags: python, sql, django, база-данных, архитектура

Занимаюсь созданием системы тестирования (тест с вопросами и вариантами ответов) на Django.
Архитектура БД на данный момент выглядит следующим образом:

```html
TestName(id: pk, test_name : str)
TestQuestion(id: pk, question_title : str, test_id : foreign_key_to(TestName))
QuestionVariant(id: pk, variant_title: str, is_correct : bool, question_id : foreign_key_to(TestQuestion))
```

Не уверен, что для вывода данных теста удобно постоянно джойнить таблицы и фильтровать данные по test_id и question_id.

Как бы вы решали эту задачу для устранения такого неудобства?

Comment: Два вопроса в одном - хорошая причина для закрытия. Оно тебе надо? Раздели на два отдельных вопроса. Тем более что один по веб-формам, второй по SQL. Тут отвечу на второй.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Архитектура БД на данный момент выглядит следующим образом
>
> ...
>
> Так же не уверен, что для вывода данных теста удобно постоянно джойнить таблицы и фильтровать данные по test_id и question_id.

Связывание и фильтрация никаких неудобств не составляют - это не просто нормальная практика, а базовый принцип работы с данными. Так что не то что вопрос - сама постановка вопроса подобным образом лишена смысла.

Просто поверь - сервер БД создан именно для того, чтобы не просто постоянно выполнять такого рода работу, но и выполнять её максимально эффективно. И практически всегда любая попытка ему помочь оборачивается обратным эффектом. Так что по этому вопросу даже не заморачивайся. Неудобства тут НЕТ.

---

Дополнительно, в качестве доброго совета. Не используй имя `id` для первичного ключа. Используй имена полей в той форме, в которой у тебя названы ссылающиеся поля. Т.е. `test_id` и в таблице `TestQuestion`, как сейчас, и первичный ключ в таблице `TestName`.

Во-первых, убирается неоднозначность. Сразу по имени поля понятно, что в нём (а по алиасу таблицы - ещё и где именно). Во-вторых, вместо `JOIN .. ON t1.id = t2.user_id` можно писать более короткое и логичное `JOIN .. USING (user_id)`.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ!

Comment: @Akina на sql.ru вернуться не желаешь?

Comment: @Вадим Он... как бы это повежливее... дохлый он, в общем. *Не удается получить доступ к сайту. Превышено время ожидания ответа от сайта sql.ru.*

Comment: https://nosql.itwrks.org/forum/forums.php :) жив курилка! просто надо найтись всем

Comment: @Вадим Близко не лежал. Только внешне похож. Но даже по набору разделов и никам (ладно бы участников - мало ли в Инете идиотов,- но и среди модераторского состава) - помойка, по крайней мере потенциально с крайне высокой вероятностью. Уже сейчас 95% тем - это флейм либо флуд. Не, в таком я как-то не хочу "находиться".

Comment: дак потому и есть такой, что старого состава нет. мало кто из старых знает про это. давай кого знаешь приглашай восстановим былое, жаль, стока времени общались.... может удастся возродить